# How can I translate indexes that are odd to an index {0,1,2,3,4,5}?

Tags: java, arrays, math

```
public static int[] Separator1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersGenerated.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            numberSet1[i / 2] = numbersGenerated[i];
        }

    }
    return numberSet1;
}

public static int[] Separator2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersGenerated.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            numberSet2[i / 2] = numbersGenerated[i];
        }

    }
    return numberSet2;
}
```

In the code above, I can successfully produce indexes from even numbers for `numberSet1`, but when I try to produce indexes for `numberSet2` I cannot. The reason I cannot produce indexes for that array is because the numbers are odd. The `[i / 2]` is just a place holder by the way because I have no idea what formula I could use to produce the indexes.

Example for `Separator1`: 
`numbersGenerated = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100};`

`numberSet1` would return values of `{10,30,50,70,90}`

I want `numberSet2` to return values of `{20,40,60,80,100}`

I am open to any suggestions because earlier I was actually trying to use one Separator and return 2 values from it and I found out that it would not work. The code just needs to be able to separate an array into 2 distinctive arrays with the same values from the first one.

**Thank You, for your time :D**

Comment: Why do you want to translate indexes that are prime like that?

Comment: So that I can make another array with the other values left in `numbersGenerated`
For Example: `numberSet2` would have return values of `{20,40,60,80,100}`

Comment: And how are any of those numbers "prime"?

Comment: Do you mean even and odd?

Comment: How are you checking primeness?

Comment: Sorry, I looked at the first few numbers and thought they were all prime and yes now that I see it, I do mean even and odd.

Comment: @CaptainCloud The (i/2) indexing in your Seperator2 method is off - please see my answer on how to index into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're wanting to put numbers from even indexes into one collection and numbers from odd indexes into a separate collection.  Example - indexes 0, 2, 4, 6, ... are returned from `Seperator1`, and indexes 1, 3, 5, 7, ... are returned from `Seperator2`.

Here is the basic logic.

```
public static int[] Separator1() {
    for(int i = 0; i < numbersGenerated.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) { // Grabs even numbered indexes
            numberSet1[i / 2] = numbersGenerated[i]; // Places even numbered indexes
        }
    }
    return numberSet1;
}

public static int[] Separator2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersGenerated.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) { // Odd numbered indexes
            numberSet2[(i - 1) / 2] = numbersGenerated[i]; // Places odd numbered indexes
        }
    }
    return numberSet2;
}
```

`(i - 1) / 2` Example:

```
For index 1 | ((1 - 1) / 2) = 0
For index 3 | ((3 - 1) / 2) = 1
For index 5 | ((5 - 1) / 2) = 2
....
```

You might want to consider renaming the methods to something like `getEvenIndexes` and `getOddIndexes` in the future to avoid confusion.

---

Side Note:  Java convention has method names start with a lowercase letter - this will make it easier for other people to read your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to this and I would love for someone to give us an explanation why yours did not work.  I thought i/2 by integer math would round down to the nearest integer. but give this a try.

```
public static int[] Separator2() {
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbersGenerated.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        numberSet2[counter] = numbersGenerated[i];
        counter++;
    }

}
return numberSet2;
```